# Remove certain parts of a statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I've got an application which generates a number of SQL statements, whose selection fields all contain `AS` clauses, like so:

```
SELECT TOP 200 [customer_name] AS [Customer Name], [customer_age] AS [Customer Age], AVG([customer_age]) AS 'Average Customer Age' FROM [tb_customers] GROUP BY [customer_age]
```

My statements will always be in that format. My task is to parse them so that "TOP 200" is removed, as well as all the `AS` clauses **except for aggregates**. In other words, I would want to parse the statements and in that case it would end up like so:

```
SELECT [customer_name], [customer_age], AVG([customer_age]) AS 'Average Customer Age' FROM [tb_customers] GROUP BY [customer_age]
```

How would I go about doing this? Is it even possible, as it seems like a very complex parsing task since the amount of fields is never going to be the same. If it helps, I've got a variable which stores the amount of fields in it (not including aggregates).

Comment: **Bear in mind**, that `SELECT [customer_name], [customer_age], AVG([customer_age]) AS 'Average Customer Age' FROM [tb_customers] GROUP BY [customer_age]` *is not a valid* sql statement in SQL Server, the `[customer_name]` is not included in either a `GROUP BY` nor in an aggregate function.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the SQL generator code instead ?

Comment: It's just a quick example to illustrate @MahmoudGamal - I'm aware it's not valid :) I just wanted to show that I can have multiple fields with the group by, thats all

Comment: It's possible @Laurent, but this should be a faster, quicker task with less code generated. What would you recommend? Your approach would add significant code throughout the application, while my desired approach would only take a few lines in one central class

Comment: I fully understand your concerns. IMHO, Your solution can be applied as a "quick fix", but in the long term, I would try to ensure that this new scenario is included in the SQL generation code at its root level: if we dont want TOP nor AS statements, it is better that the SQL generation code is aware of this and avoid to create them.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent, I'll consider going down this route :)

Comment: A better approach to parsing SQL is to use a real SQL parser. [TopCoder publishes one such parser](http://topcoder.com/home/blog/component/sql-parser-2/), complete with source code and all, which I have tried in the past, and know that it does a good job parsing reasonably complex SQL statements. Once you get a parsed representation, you can modify it, and format it back as SQL, all within the same component code. Free membership in TopCoder is required to download the component. I do not know the terms for commercial use of it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regular expression, like replace all occurrences of

```
AS \[.*?\]
```

with empty text

or all occurrences of

```
AS \[.*?\],
```

with a comma ",".

The question mark "?" is important here as it turns off greedy matching.

Comment: Would this also remove the aggregates though?

Comment: No, it would not, as aggregate labels are wrapped in single quotes and not square brackets.